# What code is run behind Git GUI buttons in Rstudio

Tags: git, rstudio

I am looking for documentation for the Git GUI buttons available in RStudio.

When your .Rproj is in a git repo, a "Git" tab appears in the upper-right window in RStudio, providing a git gui. The buttons include Diff, Commit, Pull, Push, and History. There is also a branch dropdown and staging area. I believe these are just running shell git code in the background, and I am looking for the details.

For example, it is not clear to me whether the Pull button runs `git pull` vs `git pull --rebase origin [current branch]`. Does the "Staged" checkmark actually add a file, or does it simply tell "Commit" to do an add and a commit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While these commands are not documented, you can view the source code to see what commands are being executed:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionGit.cpp

For example, the Git Pull implementation lives here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/f64d11505f8620337f8fe45cc80b364b6923b2c0/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionGit.cpp#L971-L975

and you can see that a vanilla `git pull` is being executed.